# Failing to query Neo4J database with Out of memory errors

Tags: java, neo4j

We have a moderate size graph having 6330318 nodes and 6779549 relationships. After having imported the data, I have been unable to start the neo4j server or the neo4j shell. Both of them fail with `GC overhead limit exceeded` errors. I am giving a maximum heap space size of 12 GB to the JVM. The server has 15GB RAM. The neo4j.properies has following configuration for memory mapped IO.

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=400M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=520M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=10M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=10M
```

We don't have any properties in the graph, therefore such low values for propertystore related settings.

I have also written a small web application for querying the graph, which is deployed on Tomcat. That also failed to query the graph with the following errors

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2245)
    java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
    java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:242)
    java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:216)
    java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:208)
    java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:440)
    org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfos.addInternal(FieldInfos.java:216)
    org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfos.read(FieldInfos.java:361)
    org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfos.<init>(FieldInfos.java:74)
    org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:80)
    org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:116)
    org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:94)
    org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.<init>(DirectoryReader.java:105)
    org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlyDirectoryReader.<init>(ReadOnlyDirectoryReader.java:27)
    org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader$1.doBody(DirectoryReader.java:78)
    org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:709)
    org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:72)
    org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:256)
    org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.init(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:249)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:483)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72)
    org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:423)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:164)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:339)
    org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:90)
    org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:199)
    com.socialtwist.rnet.web.RnetNeo4jServlet.init(RnetNeo4jServlet.java:44)
```

We have deployed the application on a server with 16 GB of RAM and have given Tomcat a heap space of 12 GB. What other tuning options are available for Neo4J to make this work under reasonable response time?

Comment: So does it not start at all or do you only see problems when you send a query? One thing to keep in mind is that the memory Neo4j uses is the heap + MMIO so I might reduce the heap size a bit so you're not taking up nearly all the memory of the whole machine.

Could you share the query you're running?

Comment: The max heap size for tomcat is 12 GB while the server has 16 GB memory in whole, so there seems to be plenty of free memory for memory mapped IO (there is no other major process running apart from tomcat).
I am trying to run this basic query:
START referee=node(*) MATCH referee<-[r:IS_FRIEND_OF]-(referrer:User) WHERE referee:`1677523` RETURN referrer;

Comment: BTW, the tomcat process does start but it starts to give Out of Memory errors on querying the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many labels do you have in your graph? Something is very off with your graph and query. I think you confused labels (types) with id's

Create index on :User(id);

MATCH (referee:User)<-[:IS_FRIEND_OF]-(referrer:User) WHERE referee.id=1677523 RETURN referrer;

Should return instantly after you fixed you graph model, i.e. Removed all numeric labels

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to be the issue. I have tried out with even a bigger graph having 50068607 nodes and 84252339 edges. It is returning queries within 2-3 ms.